# Returning back an array of collections in mongoose

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose

I am new to mongoose and I tried to search a lot in order to convert a mongoose collection into an array but it returns an error that toArray() is not a method.So here is the alternative way I am trying to convert into an array.I am using passport js method for authentication and for that i require all the user information as an array.I am tryin to implement the example given in

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/express3/app.js

to mongoose driven data.

Heres the snippet I am trying to use for converting a mongoose collection into an Array.

```
ContactProvider.prototype.findByusername=function(callback){
    var users=Post.find({});
    var user=toObject((JSON.parse(users))) ;
    callback(null,user);

};
```

I got the following error

```
undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at ContactProvider.findByusername (/home/r121/Desktop/nilesh/cmarin-MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog-4a5e5e9/postprovider.js:60:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/r121/Desktop/nilesh/cmarin-MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog-4a5e5e9/app.js:138:37)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

How should I return an array of those collections backs.Can anyone please guide me with the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to utilize the callback of the .find() method, then calling the toObject() on the returned results. Example

```
Post.find({}).exec(function(err, o) {
    callback(err, o)
});
```

Edit: Removed redundant toObject() call for reasons mentioned in comments by JohnnyHK

Comment: Does the 'err' variable contain anything? And there are definitely Posts in the db?

Comment: `o` is an array of Post objects; `toObject` is a method on a single Post object.

Comment: Ah yes of course, I got confused with the `findOne` method. This makes the `toObject()` call redundant and all you have to send to the callback is the `o` itself